# Beep() function when cross-compiling on Linux for Windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, codeblocks, cross-compiling

I've used this guide to set-up cross-compiler in Linux for Windows binaries:
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code::Blocks_and_Cross_Compilers

Simple programs works and generates .exe files as expected. However when I try to use specific **Windows.h** functions - no reasonable results.
For example Code:

```
int main()
{
    Beep(1000, 1000);
    MessageBeep(MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Don't produce system beep sound neither `MessageBeep()` works. Any suggestions ?

**EDIT:**

[Output from `nm`](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=73470471197884292053)

[Output from `objdump`](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=18204914191571127314)

I don't know is it related, but also when I execute this binary on my Linux system I get some warning on console:

> fixme:msvcrt:MSVCRT__wsopen_s : pmode 0x01b6 ignored

Comment: What's the output if you run `dumpbin /exports` on the generated .exe?

Comment: But are you running the code on Windows? A cross-compiler creates code for a target system, by a different system, but it cannot usually be run on the system that created it.

Comment: If it doesn't fall over when you run it then the problem is at the back-end.  Turn up your speaker volume :)  It won't hurt to trace the machine code to verify that these functions were not stubbed-out btw.

Comment: @weather I don't think that's true. Do you have a source for that claim? A console app can call API functions like MessageBeep just fine.

Comment: @CodyGray you are right thank you, deleted irrelevant comment.

Comment: @weather I'm running it on Linux Mint with Wine. I need exactly this - to test cross-compiled Windows code on Wine interpretation.

Comment: Your nm and objdump links are inaccessible. Better copy-paste the output if its needed.